# Find the path of the file when we have only file name as a String literal in Java

Tags: java

I want to get the full path of the file which is located in a directory in my computer. I don't have anything except the name of the file which is in the form of String value.for example I have "abc.txt" as file name and I want the full path i.e. ../../xyz/abc.txt. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: So what if there is more than one file called "abc.txt" on your computer?

Comment: In this case the file names are unique

Comment: How do you know it exists at all?

Comment: `../../xyz/abc.txt` is not a full path. Unclear what you're asking. Do you perhaps need the current working directory when executing your code?

Comment: I code in netbeans IDE. I have created one project, in the project directory there is a folder named dataset in that folder there is another folder called textFiles and in that I have all the files. I have all the names of the files which are present in textFiles directory but to read the file in java I need file path starting from project directory.so how could I get the path of particular file through which I can read the file?

Comment: "To read the file in java I need file path starting from project directory": No you don't. You just need to know where it is relative to the deployed JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it should be something like:

```
public void searchFiles(File root, String fileName, List<String> result) {

    for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()){
            searchFiles(file, fileName, result);
        } else if (file.isFile() && file.getName().equals(fileName)) {
            result.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}

File root = new File("/");
List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
searchFiles(root, "abc.txt", result);

for (String path : result) {
    System.out.println("File found: " + path);
}
```

However, I think you are in the wrong way.

Comment: Note that `!file.isFile()` does not necessarily mean that it is in fact a directory. In this case it is better to ask for `file.isDirectory()` (and reverse the `if` branches accordingly).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have just edited the answer